# Weird windows split issue with fonts and toolbar

Tags: fonts, window-splitting

I found that after a recent upgrade, the window is not working splitting correctly. In some circumstances, the window is always split vertically, no matter how width the window is and even in the maximized frame (270 chars x 80 lines).

Supposed the frame is maximized (270 chars x 80 lines), and a single window is there

- Run `emacs -q`, maximized the frame, `M-x describe-fuction require`, the windows is correctly split horizontally.
- Put `(tool-bar-mode -1) (set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "DM Mono" :height 110)` in empty init.el, `emacs`, maximized the frame, `M-x describe-fuction require`, the windows is split **vertically** now.
- Put `(tool-bar-mode -1)` in empty init.el, `emacs`, maximized the frame, `M-x describe-fuction require`, the windows is correctly split horizontally.
- Put `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "DM Mono" :height 110)` in empty init.el, `emacs`, maximized the frame, `M-x describe-fuction require`, the windows is correctly split horizontally.
- Put `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "DM Mono")` in empty init.el, `emacs`, maximized the frame, `M-x describe-fuction require`, the windows is correctly split horizontally.

Repeat the above process, the issue exists for font `DM Mono`, `SF Mono`, `Office Code Pro`, `Source Code Pro` etc., but does not exist for `Monego`, `Monaco` etc.

IIRC, I don't have this issue in emacs 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28. And I am not sure if it is a macOS only issue.

It took me half of the night to narrow down the issue. What is going on there? How can this happen? How to fix it?

- emacs version: `GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin23.2.0, Carbon Version 170 AppKit 2487.3) of 2024-02-01`
- OS: macOS 14.2.1 (23C71)